How to define three different areas in an ASP.NET Core micro service solution?
I've created an ASP.NET Core micro service project(Web Api), and now I need to add an area within this solution, but areas can't be defined in a Web API template, I don't have any idea for how to set up areas into it.
I think I should add a razor page to make this happen.

What's the actual question? micro service means nothing. It's been applied to everything service-related so it's no longer useful, if it ever was. ASP.NET Core does have areas, which can be defined through attributes on a controller or code

Are you looking for the equivalent of controllers and areas in Minimal APIs? That's Route groups

I Mean how to use web api for Implementing Areas.
@PanagiotisKanavos

I posted links to the actual docs. Did you check them? You can add [Area("Products")] to a Web API controller to create a controller in the Products area and add an extra route template

Thanks for your explaination and your answer

You could use of conventional routing in order to configure your requirement.
